# Could you use millions of small watch batteries in parallel to start a car?

Tags: batteries

This is an xkcd style question I grant

Assume you didn't care if the batteries exploded, that this is clearly not practical or sensible etc

But theoretically, it's the end of the world, you have access to unlimited numbers of watch batteries and infinite time, could it theoretically work?

Comment: What make and model? What propulsion energy source?

Comment: With simple batteries, you could have some 10 mW. A car need ... 50 kW. You need thus 5 millions batteries ... Wiring could be fastdious ...

Comment: At a place I used to work, a colleague was collecting CR2032 cells from scrapped products. He started stacking them in a cardboard tube. One day he got a nasty shock from the stack. I think it was up to over 300V at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one [CR2032](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf2/AAA4000/AAA4000C321.pdf) can supply 2mA at 2.4V @-10°C, to get 250A CCA (cold cranking amperes) at 7.2V (a reasonable, but not generous, rating for a car battery) you'd need 3 sets in series and 125,000 parallel in each set, so 375,000 total.

[image]

So not quite millions, at least for the common CR2032 coin cell. If the engine is warm and other conditions favorable, then fewer cells would be required. Of course you'd have to finish wiring them before the batteries self-discharged too much.

Answer (score 2):

With millions in parallel, no.  The voltage is too low.  Depending on the battery chemistry, it's likely to be in the 1.5 to 3 volt range.  You'd need several in series to get to 12 volts.

With millions in a series/parallel matrix, maybe.